# Credentials looping on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rabbitmq

I am working on a PowerShell/RabbitMQ project following this [tutorial](https://port1433.com/2017/07/21/messaging-queuing-for-the-dba-sending-data-out-into-the-world/) and I found a problem while trying to connect with a listener to RabbitMQ.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"bad_request","reason":"[{key_missing,ackmode}]"}
```

I managed to fix it out typing this line of code in the GetMessage.ps1 file:

```
"ackmode" = @("ack_requeue_true", "ack_requeue_false")[[bool]$Remove]
```

Now it works and each time I execute a query/procedure I get a message on RabbitMQ telling me what has happened.

The main problem comes that PowerShell asks me for credentials for each line on the sql result, and if I haven't executed anything yet it still asks for credentials every 3-5 seconds, even that I have saved them using:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
```

EDIT: Code for GetMessage.ps1

```
function Get-RabbitMQMessage
    {
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='defaultLogin', SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='None')]
        Param
        (
            # Name of RabbitMQ Queue.
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
            [Alias("queue", "QueueName")]
            [string]$Name = "",

            # Name of the virtual host to filter channels by.
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [Alias("vh", "vhost")]
            [string]$VirtualHost,

            # Name of the computer hosting RabbitMQ server. Defalut value is localhost.
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [Alias("HostName", "hn", "cn")]
            [string]$ComputerName = $defaultComputerName,


            # Number of messages to get. Default value is 1.
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [int]$Count = 1,

            # Indicates whether messages should be removed from the queue. Default setting is to not remove messages.
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [switch]$Remove,

            # Determines message body encoding.
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [ValidateSet("auto", "base64")]
            [string]$Encoding = "auto",

            # Indicates whether messages body should be truncated to given size (in bytes).
            [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [int]$Truncate,

            # Indicates what view should be used to present the data.
            [ValidateSet("Default", "Payload", "Details")]
            [string]$View = "Default",


            # UserName to use when logging to RabbitMq server.
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='login')]
            [string]$UserName,

            # Password to use when logging to RabbitMq server.
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='login')]
            [string]$Password,

            # Credentials to use when logging to RabbitMQ server.
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='cred')]
            [PSCredential]$Credential
        )Begin
    {
        $Credential = NormaliseCredentials
        $cnt = 0
    }
    Process
    {
        if (-not $VirtualHost)
        {
            # figure out the Virtual Host value
            $p = @{}
            $p.Add("Credentials", $Credential)
            if ($ComputerName) { $p.Add("ComputerName", $ComputerName) }

            $queues = Get-RabbitMQQueue @p | ? Name -eq $Name

            if (-not $queues) { return; }

            if (-not $queues.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                $VirtualHost = $queues.vhost
            } else {
                $vhosts = $queues | select vhost
                $s = $vhosts -join ','
                Write-Error "Queue $Name exists in multiple Virtual Hosts: $($queues.vhost -join ', '). Please specify Virtual Host to use."
            }
        }


        [string]$s = ""
        if ([bool]$Remove) { $s = "Messages will be removed from the queue." } else {$s = "Messages will be requeued."}
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("server: $ComputerName/$VirtualHost", "Get $Count message(s) from queue $Name. $s"))
        {
            $url = "http://$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ComputerName)):15672/api/queues/$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($VirtualHost))/$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Name))/get"

            $body = @{
                "count" = $Count
                "requeue" = -not [bool]$Remove
                "encoding" = $Encoding
                "ackmode" = @("ack_requeue_true", "ack_requeue_false")[[bool]$Remove]
            }
            if ($Truncate) { $body.Add("truncate", $Truncate) }

            $bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json

            Write-Debug "body: $bodyJson"

            $result = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Credential $Credential -AllowEscapedDotsAndSlashes -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Continue -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bodyJson

            $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "QueueName" -NotePropertyValue $Name

            foreach ($item in $result)
            {
                $cnt++
                $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "no" -NotePropertyValue $cnt
                $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ComputerName" -NotePropertyValue $ComputerName
                $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "VirtualHost" -NotePropertyValue $VirtualHost
            }

            if ($View)
            {
                switch ($View.ToLower())
                {
                    'payload'
                    {
                        SendItemsToOutput $result "RabbitMQ.QueueMessage" | fc
                    }

                    'details'
                    {
                        SendItemsToOutput $result "RabbitMQ.QueueMessage" | ft -View Details
                    }

                    Default { SendItemsToOutput $result "RabbitMQ.QueueMessage" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "`r`nGot $cnt messages from queue $Name, vhost $VirtualHost, server: $ComputerName."
    }
}
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code (a [mcve] to be precise). In your question. Show the error(s) your getting too.

Comment: Already added the code that is giving me "problems", main thing here is that I'm getting the credential box open all the time, when it shouldn't.

Comment: *\*sigh\** Which part of "minimal" (or "complete" for that matter) is so hard for everyone to understand? Anyway, `$Credential = NormaliseCredentials` replaces the value of the parameter `$Credential` with whatever `NormaliseCredentials` returns. Check what that actually is.